# ExtJS 6.2 add components dynamically using drag and drop

Tags: select, dynamic, extjs, drag-and-drop, components

I need to implement drag and drop form in ExtJS 6.2 that adds components dynamically to a from.

I have a (grid)list on left side that contains type of components as texts, for example that list contains:

- doctors (will be combobox)
- units (will be combobox) "
- check some constraints" in my case (will be checkbox) as texts.

I want to add that component (a combobox or checkbox) to right side of my panel when I click or drag one of them.

Each component can be added more than one. Can anyone show me the way or give me an example?

I come across to grid to grid or div drag and drop examples.
Thanks.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/extjs/extjs_grid_form_dd.htm

Comment: Please review [What's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This question doesn't show any kind of research on your part (= down-vote) and doesn't pose a specific question (= down-vote) – it simply states general requirements suggesting someone else should implement or figure it for you (= down-vote). _Can anyone show me the way or give me an example?_ is ***too broad*** (= vote to close); good questions are specific and based on your own research and solution attempt (= your code).

Comment: Also when asking a question please take care which `tags` you use. Do you have all relevant tags? Your question doesn't include any programming language; but maybe should include `javascript`?. The tag-info for the included `select` tag states _Do not use this tag for questions related to: HTML <select> tag (use `html-select`)_.